# Eclipse IDE is not open in command line

Tags: eclipse

The below error message showing when i execute the "eclipse" file from command line,

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=150m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-Xverify:none
-Dosgi.instance.area=@user.dir/ZIDE
-jar /home/prabha/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/prabha/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/prabha/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /home/prabha/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata eef0026
-vm /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=150m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-Xverify:none
-Dosgi.instance.area=@user.dir/ZIDE
-jar /home/prabha/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

My JDK version is "jdk1.6.0_14", But, still throwing this error.

Kindly let me know, how can solve this problem in my machine.

Comment: can you post your eclipse.ini file?

Comment: -showsplash
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=150m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-Xverify:none

Comment: can you update your question with eclipse.ini not in comment

Comment: No, i can't understand

Comment: See answer below or see http://www.ehow.com/how_4784069_terminated-exit-code-error-eclipse.html

Comment: Hi @IswantoSan thanks for your link, i will change my jre version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be trying to use a 64-bit Eclipse with a 32-bit JRE.  They have to match with each other and the version of GTK that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OSX(which you are not, since I see `-os linux`), you can use the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a Eclipse "$@"
```

From my recollection, linux has `xdg-open` which might work for you.